# How to set text file encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, text, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

How can I set a text file ENCODING (for instance UTF-8) in PHP?

Let me show you my problem. This is my code:

```
<?php 
file_put_contents('test.txt', $data); // data is some non-English text with UTF-8 charset
?>
```

Output: `Ø§Ù`!

`fwrite()` has the similar output.

But when I create the `test.txt` by notepad and set the charset **UTF-8** the output is what I want.
I wanna set the charset in the PHP file.

Now this is my question: How to set text file encoding by PHP?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHP does not apply an encoding when storing text in a file: it stores data exactly as it is laid out in the string.

You mention that you have problems opening the file in `notepad.exe`. That text editor is not very good at guessing the encoding of the file you are opening; if the text is encoded in UTF-8 you must choose to open it as UTF-8. Use another text editor if possible. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a popular replacement.

If you must use `notepad.exe`, as a last resort, write a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the file before you write anything else; this will make it recognize the file as UTF-8 while potentially making the file unusable for other purposes (see the Wikipedia article for details).

```
file_put_contents("file.txt", "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $data);
```

Answer (score 14):

You may try this using [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding)

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'auto');
file_put_contents('test.txt', $data);
```

Also check [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

**Update :** (try this and find the right encoding for your text)

```
foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){ 
    echo mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";    
}
```

Also, try this on [GitHub](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8).

Comment: The text encoding is OK. I want to change the file encoding.

Comment: @Programmer.zip, Did you try this ? This is what needs for encoding.

Comment: About 10 times since last night:(

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', utf8_encode($data));
```

Comment: Are you really sure, that your string is really UTF-8? Test it with http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.iconv-get-encoding.php

Comment: it returns ISO-8859-1 using `'internal_encoding'` and `'output_encoding'`, I use `iconv_set_encoding()` and set it UTF-8, but didn't work yet..

Comment: $data = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8", $data);

Comment: I think there is no problem about text encoding (because when I create text file by notepad it works) and I tried this code many times but It don't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which converts a string array into a utf8 encoded string array and another to decode and write to a notepad file for you.

```
<?php
function utf8_string_encode(&$array){
    $myencode = function(&$value,&$key){
        if(is_string($value)){
            $value = utf8_encode($value);
        } 
        if(is_string($key)){
            $key = utf8_encode($key);
        }
        if(is_array($value)){
            utf8_string_encode($value);
        }
    };
    array_walk($array,$func);
    return $array;
}
?>
```