# PHP - writing special characters with fwrite- looks good in notepad but wrong in browser

Tags: php, encoding, text-files, special-characters, fwrite

I have a small issue with writing special characters (Danish, but also some symbols) text to .txt-files with PHP.
Take this example:

```
<?php

$words = "å æ ø"; 

$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
fwrite($file, ($words));
fclose($file);

?>
```

Above code will work fine and looks correct when I open it in notepad. But for a online purpose I need to open the generated .txt-file with a browser (fx. Firefox) and in the browser the characters are not shown correctly unless I chose "Unicode" as "character encoding" from the show-menu in Firefox, default character encoding in Firefox is "western".

If I make a normal .txt-file with notepad and write "å æ ø" and saving it the normal way it looks correctly in a browser.

I have been searching around looking for information about encoding options for the fwrite but I don't really know where to start.

Kind Regards

Comment: fwrite just writes out what you give it, so the string in PHP already is unicode.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067492/how-to-set-text-file-encoding-in-php#19071091). It's not PHP's fault, but the browser's.

Comment: Use 
    `$words = "å æ ø"; 
    $f=fopen("test.txt","w"); 
    fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 
    fwrite($f,$words); 
    fclose($f);`

Comment: it seems you have to use set char-set  with php

Comment: Thanks to AHjeebon, this saved my night: fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));

Comment: thausl - Thanks for your reply but Its not really helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the following: As the UTF-8 byte-order mark is '\xef\xbb\xbf' we should add it to the document's header.

```
<?php
    function writeStringToFile($file, $string) {
       $f = fopen($file, "wb");
       $string= "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$string; // utf8 bom
       fputs($f, $string);
       fclose($f);
     }
?>
```

[read about BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, its not working but thats due to a error in your code. $file = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$string; should be $string = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$string;